# Calling PHP function from AGI not working

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I'm using PHPAGI script telling the user to dial a number and then pass the number to the function to dial out, but it isn't working. I'm trying to call the function from my script but it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
$agi->text2wav("please enter number to dial");
$num = $agi->exec("Read","pin,,,3,120");
$temp = $agi->get_variable("pin");
$pin = trim($temp["data"]);
dialout("$pin");

function dialout($pin)
{
    $agi=new AGI();
    $agi->exec_dial("SIP/$pin");
    $Answeredtime = $agi->get_variable("ANSWEREDTIME");
    $agi->hangup ();
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error message? (If so please post the error.)

Comment: @ jpaugh no error message.

Answer (score 0):

1) stop asterisk

```
asterisk -rx " core stop now"
```

2) start asterisk at current console

```
asterisk -vvvvgc
```

NOT stop it.

3) issue

```
 agi set debug on
```

After that you will have much more info and php errors from your script

Comment: im getting this error `Notice: Undefined variable: agi in /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/password.php on line 161` which is `$agi->exec_dial("SIP/$pin");` `$pin` variable.

Comment: how to set global variable.

Comment: sorry,it is not a question for SO. We already determined your issue. Read any php book for other issues.